# Why does LaTeX add an unneeded space under this table?

Tags: tables, math-mode, align, tabularx, line-spacing

[image]

The space between the last row and the bottom rule is too much. Why is this happening? How can I remove such space?

My source code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,array,booktabs,multirow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}

\newcolumntype{C}{ >{ \arraybackslash \Centering } X }
\renewcommand \tabularxcolumn [1] { >{ \centering } m{#1} }
\newcommand {\scalelinespace} [1] {\rule{0pt}{#1\normalbaselineskip}}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[h]

    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}[h]{>{\hsize=0.5\hsize}C| >{\hsize=1.7\hsize}C| >{\hsize=1\hsize}CC|}

        \toprule

        \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Math} & \textbf{More Math} \\

        \midrule

        Foo & 

            $\begin{aligned}
                A &= x^{2} + y^{3} \\[-1.5mm]
                BC &= x^{3} - y^{2}
            \end{aligned}$

        &

            $\begin{aligned}
            x &\leftarrow x \thinspace (1 - \alpha)  \\[-1.5mm]
            y &\leftarrow y \thinspace (1 + \beta) 
            \end{aligned}$



        \\

        \Xcline{3-3}{0.2mm}


        Bar & 

                \hspace{4.1mm} $D = x y + w_{z}$

                \text{Note if } $A>D \text{ then } D \leftarrow AB+C$

        &

            $w_{z} \leftarrow w_{z} \thinspace (1 + q)$


        \\ 

        \bottomrule


    \end{tabularx}

\end{table}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Please note that using vertical lines together with the `booktabs` package is not advisable, see for example all the gaps around the lines...

The additional space vanishes if some of the unnecessary empty lines are removed:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,array,booktabs,multirow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}[h]{l|C|l}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Math} & \textbf{More Math}\\
    \midrule
    Foo &  $\begin{aligned}
                A &= x^{2} + y^{3} \\[-1.5mm]
                BC &= x^{3} - y^{2}
           \end{aligned}$
        &  $\begin{aligned}
            x &\leftarrow x \thinspace (1 - \alpha)  \\[-1.5mm]
            y &\leftarrow y \thinspace (1 + \beta) 
           \end{aligned}$\\
     \cmidrule{3-3}
        Bar & 
        \makecell[c]{$D = x y + w_{z}$ \\
        \text{Note if } $A>D \text{ then } D \leftarrow AB+C$} &    
        $w_{z} \leftarrow w_{z} \thinspace (1 + q)$\\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

[image]

(I removed the manual messing with columns widths, otherwise the usage of `tabularx` does not make sense and a normal table width fixed widths would be better)